# Unidirectional one-to-one relationship

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

How do I achieve a unidirectional one to one relationship for Person and PersonData?

```
@Entity
public class Person  {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // @OneToOne...?
    // ...?
    private PersonData data;
}

@Entity
public class PersonData {
    @Id
    private long personId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `@OneToOne` annotation with the `@JoinColumn` annotation to specify the primary key of the other entity:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="personId")
private PersonData data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` to have shared primary key in PersonData Table.

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "personId")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private PersonData data;

}

@Entity
public class PersonData implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @OneToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
    private Long personId;
}
```

For more details:

https://github.com/abhilekhsingh041992/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/example/springboot/jpa/domain/Person.java

https://github.com/abhilekhsingh041992/spring-boot-samples/blob/master/jpa/src/main/java/example/springboot/jpa/domain/PersonData.java

Comment: This is bidirectional. Don't want PersonData to know about Person. It should only reference it by id (personId).

Comment: I didn't know that. I edited the answer. Please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: Are you getting any error? In more details link I provided the sample project which is running successfully.

Comment: Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'account_id', table 'InvoiceSettings'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The problem appears when trying to do something like:
Person p = new Person();
p.setPersonData(new PersonData());
em.persist(p);

Comment: How you using table 'InvoiceSettings'? In the question it is not mentioned.

Comment: JPA +2 `One To One' attribute type should not be 'Long'`

Answer (score 0):

Add Person as `targetEntity` to `@OneToOne`  in PersonData :

```
@OneToOne(targetEntity = Person.class)
private Person person;
```